# Time datatype doesn't seems to work

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following code for creating a table, but it fails, and I don't know why:

```
CREATE TABLE Cut_Job
( assembly_id numeric (9, 0),
  dept_no numeric (9, 0),
  process_id numeric (9, 0),
  job_no numeric (9, 0),
  date_commenced date,
  date_completed date,
  machine_type varchar (20),
  machine_time time (0), --this is line 63
  labor_time time (0),
  primary key (dept_no, process_id));
```

And the error it shows is the following:

```
Error at Command Line:63 Column:16
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I don't understand why it fails.

Comment: `time` is not a valid data type in Oracle.  What do you intend to store there?  It's not clear to me from the column names whether you want to store a `timestamp` or an `interval`.

Comment: I am trying to store at least hours:minutes spent doing something, so it doesn't have an specific day, month or year, just time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to store an [`interval` in Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50992).  `time` is not a data type that exists in Oracle.

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  CREATE TABLE Cut_Job
  2  ( assembly_id numeric (9, 0),
  3    dept_no numeric (9, 0),
  4    process_id numeric (9, 0),
  5    job_no numeric (9, 0),
  6    date_commenced date,
  7    date_completed date,
  8    machine_type varchar (20),
  9    machine_time interval day to second(0),
 10    labor_time interval day to second(0),
 11*   primary key (dept_no, process_id))
SQL> /

Table created.
```

Comment: Thanks. Where can I read more on this? I am looking it up, but I hardly understand anything I read on it.

Comment: @Yokhen - I added a link to the Oracle documentation that has an example of using intervals.

Answer (score 0):

The data type is not "time" but

```
TIMESTAMP
```

and don't define the length.

Comment: @Yokhen - You've quoted the documentation for SQL Server which does have a `time` data type.  Are you using Oracle as your tags indicate?  Or SQL Server?

Comment: I am using SQL Developer which belongs to Oracle.
Are those two above different?

Comment: @Yokhen - SQL Developer is a GUI created by Oracle corporation.  You can use SQL Developer with the Oracle database (created by Oracle corporation), SQL Server (created by Microsoft), or a number of other databases created by different vendors.  Normally, people using SQL Developer are working with an Oracle database but not always.

Comment: I see what you are saying now. That clears up a lot of things.
Is there an API (or something like that) for SQL Developer out there? The only one well structured and easy to understand that I've found, has been the one for SQL Server, apparently.

Comment: @Yokhen - What would an API for SQL Developer do for you?  It's certainly possible to write plug-ins that work with SQL Developer.  I'm hard-pressed to believe that is what you are asking for.  Maybe you are asking about documentation for the Oracle database?

Comment: Yes, a documentation I think is what I meant. Sorry I don't know the exact term for it is. But no worries, I think I found it :)